# Compare two character vectors in R based on vector of strings

Tags: r, string

I have two `lists` `A` and `B`. The `dates` in `A` are `2000 - 2022` while those in `B` are `2023-2030`.

`names(A)` and `names(B)` give the follow character vectors:

```
a <- c("ACC_a_his", "BCC_b_his", "Can_c_his", "CES_d_his")
b <- c("ACC_a_fu", "BCC_b_fu", "Can_c_fu", "CES_d_fu","FGO_c_fu")
```

Also, I have a string vector, `c` which is common across the names in `a` and `b`:

```
c=c("ACC","BCC", "Can", "CES", "FGO")
```

Note that the strings in `c` do not always appear in the same position in filenames. The string can be at the beginning, middle or end of filenames.

**Challenge**

1. Using the strings in `c` I would like to get the difference (i.e., which name exists in `b` but not in `a` or vice versa) between the names in `a` and `b`

`Expected output` = `"FGO_c_fu"`

2. `rbind` (or whatever is best) matching `dataframes` in lists `A` and `B` if the names are similar based on string in `c`

Comment: So, for the names `a` and `b` you only care about the first 3 characters? You can look define `a3 <- substr(a, 1, 3)` and `b3 <- substr(b, 1, 3)` and then look at `setdiff(a3, b3)` and `setdiff(b3, a3)`. Or if you want to get everything before the first `_` then you could use regex to get that.

Comment: @GregorThomas the strings in `c` do not always appear in the same position in filenames. The string can be at the beginning, middle or end of filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update: See OP's comment:**

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
# or just library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  mutate(x = str_extract(value, paste(c, collapse = "|"))
         ) %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  filter(!any(row_number() > 1)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  pull(value)

[1] "FGO_c_fu"
```

**First answer:**
Here is an alternative approach:

1. We create a list
2. the vectors are of unequal length
3. With `data.frame(lapply(my_list,` length<-`, max(lengths(my_list)))) we create a data frame`
4. pivot longer and group by all before the first underline
5. remove NA and filter:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)

my_list <- tibble::lst(a, b)
df <- data.frame(lapply(my_list, `length<-`, max(lengths(my_list)))) 
 
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(x = sub("\\_.*", "", value)) %>% 
  filter(!any(row_number() > 1)) %>% 
  na.omit() %>% 
  pull(value)
```

```
[1] "FGO_c_fu"
```

Comment: the above gives `character(0)` on actual files. Actual filenames are longer than 20 characters. The above is just a sample. Thus, a generic solution that does not rely on number of characters in filenames will suffice. Also, note that the strings in c do not always appear in the same position in filenames. The string can be at the beginning, middle or end of filenames. Please do not forget PART 2 of the question.

Comment: Please see my update. Hopefully this will work.

Comment: It works on sample files but not on actual files. Here is the name from an actual file: `temp_month_ACC_baseline_p1f1_gn`. A generic solution that uses the strings in `c` to differentiate `a` and `b` is desired. You have not used `c` yet.

Comment: I thought to use c in `paste(c, collapse = "|")`?

Comment: yes, use `c` in the solution. Only the strings in `c` are common between names in `a` and `b`

Comment: the update does the trick. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please you forgot PART 2 of the question. Using the strings in `c` how can I concatenate (`rbind`) matching dataframes in lists `A` and `B` if the names are similar based on strings in `c`?.  Dataframes in `A` and `B` have equal columns and headings. The `Output` list `C` is `A` appended to top of `B`.

Comment: The second part should be a separate question with a detailed question and the expected output!